# Facebook API: Page access token is missing scopes

Tags: facebook-graph-api

After retrieving a page access token using a user access token, some scopes are missing.

I use the user access token with these details:

```
"app_id": "123",
"type": "USER",
"application": "lorem",
...
"scopes": [
    "pages_show_list",
    "pages_messaging",
    "pages_messaging_subscriptions",
    "pages_manage_metadata",
    "public_profile"
],
```

Then I request the page access token from endpoint:
`https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts`

I receive a page access token:

```
"app_id": "412378670482",
"type": "PAGE",
"application": "lorem",
...
"profile_id": "123",
"scopes": [
    "pages_show_list",
    "public_profile"
],
```

Can anybody explain why the scope has been reduced?

The user that created the USER token has "full page" access to the page.

#### EDIT Full page token debug:

The most remarkable thing is here, that the profile_id is not listed in the granular scopes of e.g. "pages_manage_metadata". So the reduced scope reflects the missing ids.

```
"app_id": "3926422237",
"type": "PAGE",
"application": "lorem",
"data_access_expires_at": 1639517367,
"expires_at": 0,
"is_valid": true,
"issued_at": 1603451677,
"profile_id": "1023865413",
"scopes": [
    "pages_show_list",
    "public_profile"
],
"granular_scopes": [
    {
        "scope": "pages_show_list"
    },
    {
        "scope": "pages_messaging",
        "target_ids": [
            "2053841064733",
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "scope": "pages_messaging_subscriptions",
        "target_ids": [
            "2053841064733",
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "scope": "pages_manage_metadata",
        "target_ids": [
            "2053841064733",
            ...
        ]
    }
],
"user_id": "16954674",
"expires_at_dt": "1970-01-01",
"data_access_expires_at_dt": "2021-12-14"
}
```

Comment: Can reproduce that in Graph API Explorer, it always shows the same permissions for both the user and the page token. Can you show the full result of https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ for the page token (minus personal, identifiable user data)?

Comment: So looks like all the relevant permissions are there, but some of them are only listed as "granular_scopes", because they were granted to apply to a specific page only. (Or a set of pages, so that below the token for a specific page, you would only get that one page listed.)

Comment: I added some more info. For the missing scopes the pages id is not listed in the granular scopes. Thats the main question. User has scope "pages_manage_metadata" and full access to page, but page token has no "pages_manage_metadata" scope. How is this possible?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about, `pages_manage_metadata` is in the debug output you have shown.

Comment: Yes, but not for the page_id of the token.

Comment: What ID is it then? Can't really see right now, why a page token would include IDs to other objects.